# place footer at bottom only if page is "short"

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have  a website with several pages. each page has different height (obvious, but i mention it).

what i would like to achieve is that if the content of the page is lower then the browser viewport, the footer tag will get a fixed position and will be aligned to the bottom of the page.

iv'e tried this js:

```
$(function(){
if ($(document).height() > $("footer").offset().top+44) {
        $("footer").addClass('fixbottom');
    }
}
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(document).height() > $("footer").offset().top+44) {
        $("footer").addClass('fixbottom');
    }
});
```

and that css:

```
.fixbottom {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}


footer {
height:44px;
    background: #7abde9;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

the top+44 in my jquery is because my footer tag is 44 height
iv'e used the document ready and window resize to make sure all situations should meet, but unfortunately that's does not seem to work in any case.

any help should be greatly appriciated

Comment: See [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this.

There is a method called "[stickyfooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)" which delivers a way to get the footer always to the bottom, even if there is not much content.

Here is a simple example:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

#main {
    padding-bottom: 44px;
}

footer {
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYXR7/1/) to see how it works.

Comment: Micha, i want to attach to bottom only if the page content is shorter than the viewport

Comment: Changed CSS and added some JavaScript to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYXR7/3/). It seems not working there but tried on a test-page in actual chrome and firefox. There it was working.

Comment: How to make this work if footer height is not fixed? I have a few pages where contents of the footer (likes and icons) change based on the logged in user role

Comment: This is very nice! The only problem is when you don't have a fix height footer (for example if the footer is responsive and may have different height in different screen size) and there this solution simply does not work!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your problem only with CSS.

You need an element for your content and an element for the footer below.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="main">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Give #content a min-height of 100% and set a height and reverse margin-top (same as height) for #footer. To protect the last element in #content against a overlap set a margin-bottom.

```
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#footer {
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: -3em;
}
#main {
  padding-bottom: 3em;  /** height of #footer */
}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GB4vA/1/

Cameron Adams wrote an article about your problem.
http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2005/08/29/

Answer (score 2):

In plain javascript:

```
if (window.innerHeight > document.body.offsetHeight) {
      // code to make the footer stick to bottom
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buddhi741/s84zzetf/)

```
var shortContent = function() {    
  if($(window).height() > $('body').height()) {
      $('footer').addClass('shortContent');
  }

};

(function(){

   shortContent();

   $(window).resize(function() {
    shortContent();
   });

}());
```

simplyfied the js and made it work without much css

@MichaB your code needed jQuery m8

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function hideMe(id)
{
    var box=document.getElementById(id);
    box.style.display="none";

}
var bodyHeight=document.getElementById("body").offsetHeight,
    windowHeight=window.innerHeight;

if(bodyHeight<windowHeight)
{


    var footer= document.getElementById("footer");
    footer.style.position="absolute";
    footer.style.left="0px"
    footer.style.top=windowHeight-footer.offsetHeight+'px';
    footer.style.width='100%';

}   
<script>
```

on the HTML just put id="footer" to your footer div.. your welcome

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution in 2020: wrap the non-footer content in a tag and set the min-height of that tag to 100vh - the footer height:

HTML:

```
<main>
    <!--Page Content-->
</main>

<footer>
    <!--Footer Content-->
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
main {
    min-height: calc(100vh - <footer height>);
}
```

No JavaScript/jQuery needed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't like the idea of a big wrapper containing everything, so I found this solution:

```
html {
    position: relative;    /*IMPORTANT: otherwise the footer aligns to the :root, which is 100vh*/

    min-height: 100%;    /*if the page is "short", the html takes it up completely anyway*/
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 10rem;    /*this is the height of the footer (if it is not fixed you can find a way using media queries*/
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    height: 10rem;    /*set whatever you want, but remember to keep it synced with the body*/
}
```

The important thing to remember is that `margin-bottom` must be set on the `body`, since the footer it positioned inside the `html` tag which is its direct parent.

---

DISCLAIMER:

I found this solution on my own, but I didn't check whether someone else has found it out on any other questions... In that case, feel free to reference them in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using Flexbox, which has the advantage that you do not have to set the footer height explicitly.

**HTML**

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wjcbpat3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css to your footer

```
position: fixed; bottom: 0
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A7DUK/

Comment: If page is short, fixed is both short and scrollable